# how to make a script running until a certain point?

Tags: php

I got this code and for some reason $i++ doesn't work.It shows everything in the database and i just want 10 elements to be shown

```
if($i <= 10){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
            $i++;   
    }
}
```

Comment: and using `LIMIT 10` isn't an option? try a `foreach` or a `for`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix, change:

```
if($i <= 10){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
        $i++;   
    }
}
```

...to:

```
while($i <= 10 && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
    $i++;   
}
```

*Explanation:*

Once you're in the `if` conditional block, that `if` condition never gets evaluated again. Only the `while` condition gets evaluated with each loop, so move the `$i <= 10` into the `while` condition. Use an AND `&&` because you want both conditions to be true to continue looping.

But, ya, as Fred -ii- suggest, adding `LIMIT 10` to your database query would reduce the amount of data you have to handle.

Comment: Thanks for including the explanation -- it addresses the actual problem with the OP's original code, which I think is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the result on your `MySql` query with `LIMIT 10`.
[`MySql` LIMIT tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

i.e.:

```
select something from something LIMIT 10;
```

---

Answering to your direct question:
Use [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
    $i++;
    if($i > 10) {
        break;
    }  
}
```

> **[break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)**
>    ends execution of the current `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while` or
>   `switch` structure.